# Why was Beckett surprised when the Flying Dutchman attacked the Endeavour?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean

After the *Flying Dutchman* comes back Cutler Beckett says "ahh she has returned" with a smile and confidence on his face. Why is that? Did he expect the *Flying Dutchman* to attack the *Black Pearl*; if so why?

But seconds later he gets surprised when he find out that they're actually teaming up together against Beckett and his whole crew on the *Endeavour*.

Comment: Long time since I saw it but didn't Beckett think he had control of The Flying Dutchman through having the heart of Davy Jones? The latter died (after a fight with the Black Pearl) which meant he no longer had control and with Will being the new captain, they turned their attention against The Endeavour. So yes, he didn't know he had lost control and assumed TFD was still going to fight the BP again, hence his surprise when they do not.

Comment: Did he expect The flying Dutchman to attack Black Pearl if so why ? ? Yes, because he thought he was controlling her.

Answer (score 4):

The Flying Dutchman, before it went out of visual range of Beckett, was under  control of Davy Jones.

In turn Davy Jones his heart was being guarded by an officer loyal to Beckett, therefor Davy Jones (And by extent the Flying Dutchman and it's crew)  were under Beckett's command.

But Beckett did not know of the events that transpired on the ship during the maelstrom (Davy Jones being killed and being replaced as the Dutchman's captain by William Turner).

So at first he rightfully believed the ship would be on his side, but sadly for him that was no longer the case and he lost his trump card.